# pymongo most efficient aggregation for intersections

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Having a features list as `[a, b, c]`, a collection made of two fields records as:

`(obj1, [a, x, z, y])`, `(obj2, [a, b])`, `(obj3, [a, b, x, y])`, `(obj4, [a, b, c, d])`, `(obj5, [a, b, c, w])`

and a wanted result as: `(3, [obj4, obj5])`, containing the most occurrencies numbers found within the listes of the records together with the related object.

I wonder what is the most efficient aggregation to achieve that. The mine is the following, even I know the usage of $project alters the indexes, so it makes the query not efficient:

```
 aggr = db.clauses.aggregate([
        {"$project": {
            "value": 1,
            "intersection": {"$size": {"$setIntersection": ["$features", features]}}
        }},
        {"$group":
             {"_id": "$intersection",
              "group": {"$push": "$value"}}},
        {"$sort": {"_id": -1}},
        {"$limit": 1}
    ])
```